# c# ASP.net Indirect download to client from file server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

Sorry, I'm doing this first time with file server so there may be a few stupid questions.

So I need to connect to file server and let user download some file, but user shouldn't be able to access file server directly.

Is there some way to make a temp copy to web server and let user download file from there? Or maybe there are some different ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [HttpHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675(v=vs.100).aspx) to mediate between the browser and your filesystem, applying whatever restrictions you need programmatically.  [Here is a step-by-step guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544289/Restricting-files-download-using-HTTP-Handler-base).

Comment: Thx, I'll take a look.